# Error al eliminar un div dentro de otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estoy ejecutando lo siguiente desde un archivo externo si tengo grabados todos los archivos que empleo) y por más que refresque el navegador me sigue apareciendo la segunda division interna (que contiene a la clase MS-controls), talvez saben de otra opción para eliminar divs internos?

aparte estoy utilizando la biblioteca jquery_3.6.min.js

código javascript:

```
var tp = screen.width;

if (tp > 540) {
   $('#carruselLa > div:not(:first-child)').remove();
   console.log(tp);
}
```

código html:

```
<div id="carruselLa">
                        <div class="MS-content">
                           <div class="item" id="item_trj">
                              <img class="trj_img_cls" src="../RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" alt="" id="imgLA1">
                              <div class="texto_trj">
                                 <div class="nombre_producto">
                                    <h2 id="ttlLA1">título</h2>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="precio_producto">
                                    <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                                    <label id="precioLA1">0.00</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="caracteristicas">
                                    <ul id="caractLA1">
                                       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                                       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                                       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                                       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div><!-- -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="MS-controls">
                           <button class="MS-left" id="btnIzq">
                              <i class="icon-left-open"></i>
                           </button>
                           <button class="MS-right" id="btnDer">
                              <i class="icon-right-open"></i>
                           </button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

todavía no tengo hoja de estilos para esta parte.

Comment: Estas usando jQuery?  Te falta el `#` antes del `id

Comment: Ya le puse '#' al llamar el id y si estoy utilizando el jquery_3.6.min.js

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien

Comment: que bueno que funcione bien el código, ya voy a ver que tengo que actualizar en la máquina para que no me de problemas.